# What would it mean if there was a link between e and $\pi$?

Tags: soft-question

It is not even know if $\pi+e$ is rational, and the same is true for other similar expressions involving $\pi$ and $e$, but does this have an impact?

If it were, for example, proven that $\pi=ae$ or $\pi=a+e$ for a rational number $a$ would there be any consequences beyond it being a bit weird?

Comment: Not much relationship to rationality, but $e^{i\pi} = -1$.

Comment: As with a lot of these kinds of questions where the result itself isn't so amazing, it's more about the math developed to answer the question. It would likely give us a better way of determining relations between transcendental numbers.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: No, you know that at least one of $\pi + e$ and $\pi - e$ is **irrational**.  It is unlikely that either is rational.  It's also true that at least one of $\pi + e$ and $\pi e$ is irrational.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh doh. Thank you for that. Removed the stupid comment.

Comment: What about $$\frac\pi\pi=e\cdot\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

If $\pi e$ were rational, the limit points of $\exp(n! i)$ as $n \to \infty$ would be a finite set of roots of unity.

EDIT: Note that from $e = \sum_j 1/j!$ we get $n!e = (integer) + r$ where 
$$0 < r = \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty \dfrac{n!}{j!} < \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^k} = \dfrac{1}{n}$$
so $\exp(2 i n!\pi e) \to 1 $.  If $\pi e = a/b$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, then $\exp(2in! a) = (\exp(2in! \pi e))^b \to 1$ so any limit point of $\exp(in!)$ is a $2a$'th root of unity.

Comment: Wow that's pretty neat.

Comment: Why is this the case?